# Run Python script over multiple folders

Tags: python, bash, csv, automation, directory

Today im working with a Python script, this script takes multiple CSV files that are inside a folder and generate a CSV output file with averages by colums, in addition i also have multiple similar folders.
But what i do, is change manually the name of the folder and the name of the output file, as you can imagine, this process is very hard.
What I am looking for, is to do it for each folder respecting the order and the name of each corresponding folder in name and content of each output file.

I was trying using the next in my python script

```
scriptname,f1name,f2name = sys.argv
```

I also use a bash script to make it, but in this bash script, i can change the python script to run it over multiple files inside a folder, but not for multiple folders

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find ./escen10 -type f -name '*.csv' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
        nname=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/ecn/encn/") 
        python3 generator2.py $line $nname
    done
```

The python script is the next:

```
import os
import sys
from os import listdir
from csv import DictReader
from os import walk
from os import scandir
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
scriptname,f1name,f2name = sys.argv

#delimiter = ';'
#dataInFolderPath = './nodes_escen1_1/'
#outputFile = 'results_escen1_1.csv'

delimiter = ';'
dataInFolderPath = f1name
outputFile = f2name


dataInFiles = sorted(listdir(dataInFolderPath),key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1]))

#sorted_files = sorted(dataInFolderPath)
lines = []
nodes = {}
for fileName in dataInFiles:

    file = open(dataInFolderPath + fileName)
    data = DictReader(file, delimiter=delimiter)
    for line in data:
        if not line['node_code'] in nodes.keys():
            nodes[line['node_code']] = []
        nodes[line['node_code']].append([
            line['node_code'],
            line['throughput[Mbps]'],
            line['data_packets_sent'],
            line['data_packets_lost'],
            line['rts_cts_sent'],
            line['rts_cts_lost']
        ])

    file.close()

output = ''
maxData = max([len(nodes[n]) for n in nodes])
keys = list(nodes.keys())
keys.sort()

for i in range(maxData):
    if i == 0:
        output += ';'.join(['node_code;throughput[Mbps];Data packets_sent;Data_packets lost;rts_cts_sent;rts_cts_lost'] * len(keys)) + '\n'

    for key in keys:
        if key != keys[0]:
            output += ';'

        if i >= len(nodes[key]):
            output += ';;;;;'
            continue

        output += ';'.join(nodes[key][i])
    output += '\n'

f = open(outputFile, 'w')
f.write(output)
f.close()

data = pd.read_csv(outputFile,sep=';')

data = data.append({'node_code':"Promedio"},ignore_index=True)

lenght = len(data["node_code"])

for i in range(len(data.columns)//6):
    if i ==0:
        data['throughput[Mbps]'].iloc[lenght-1] = np.average(data['throughput[Mbps]'][:-1])
    else:
        data['throughput[Mbps].%i'%i].iloc[lenght-1] = np.average(data['throughput[Mbps].%i'%i][:-1])

data.to_csv(outputFile,sep=';')

print(outputFile)
```

For this reason, i hope you can help me to automate this process, using what I have available or with some other more efficient solution to realize this task, thank you in advance for any useful help, regards!

Comment: I didn't understand why you have imported so many modules and didn't use it. I would use just the os.walk to get all the folders and files. With just this module you can do it clean and efficiently

Comment: well, i'm going to try to solve it using os.walk, thanks

Comment: If you want to keep going the bash route, you can loop once on the directories (use `find -type d -name "SOMETING" -print0`), with a `while` loop like you did already.  Then loop again on the files inside each directory.